# Azure Speech Translator

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, web-chat

I need help on how to implement the speech translator c# sdk into a chatbot built with the bot framework c# sdk, so that whenever a user wants to use speech in another language, the bot can accept and translate the language speech in order to  understand it.

Comment: Have you seen this https://wellsb.com/csharp/learn/microsoft-translator-api-bot-framework/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However the tutorial used text. What I'm looking for is a scenario whereby user use speech instead of text

Comment: Is it like speech to speech translator?

Comment: Yes, it's speech translator in a bot that's built with Microsoft bot framework c# sdk

Comment: There is a sample, [17.multilingual-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot), located in the BotBuilder-Samples repo that already has the Microsoft Translator service built into it. Would this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create the connection from scratch with both Microsoft translator v(4) and Microsoft translator.

Reference Link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-how-to-signup

Comment: I have the Translator sdk, which works fine using console and mic. Now I want to integrate it to my bot that's already built with the Microsoft bot framework v4